# Why C doesn't accept newline char on source file (enclosed by D-quotes) passed as argument, and requires it to be embedded as \n?

Tags: c, syntax, string-literals

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("This is the first line
this is the second line
");
}
```

Why does this program throw error? Why can't it compile successfully and show the output as:

```
This is the first line
this is the second line
|
```

the symbol '|' here denotes blinking cursor, which is to show that the cursor moved to next, implying that after the second line a '\n' character as appeared in STDOUT.

```
                                              .
```

Comment: You need ending quotes on those strings, but you can do multiline string literals via `"string one"<NEWLINE>"string two"`, just listing the string literals without any operators/separators between them. If you want the `\n` to show up with this type of concatenation though, you'll need to explicitly include it.

Comment: String literals aren't allowed to contain actual newline characters, thought they can contain the escape sequence \n to represent one. [zero or more characters, each of which is . . . (excluding ("), \, and newline)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal)

Comment: @Rogue My question is mainly focused on "why can't the printf format string also include the '\n' character occuring in source file (as a result of me pressing enter), in other words, why don't the compiler consider every character between quotes as the format string? In this case, the opening (first) quote symbol occurs in 8th line and its matching closing quote occurs in 10th line of source code file. So Why don't the compiler consider everything between these quote symbols as the format string?

Comment: Questions of the form "Why was the language defined this way?" are often unanswerable, but in this case, I believe the answer is probably that if you forget a closing `"` character on an ordinary, single-line string literal, you don't want the compiler to blindly read the whole rest of your source file looking for it; you just want a nice error message.  (On the other hand, if you forget a closing `*/` on a comment, reading the whole rest of your source file looking for it is exactly what *does* happen!)

Comment: @Cinverse If you expect the compiler to consider everything between the quote symbols as the format string, does that include the spaces (or tabs) after the newlines?

Comment: Yes. But after seeing your comment, I realized that I didn't put `tab space` in the output given in the question, which would be the exact behaviour I had in my mind.

Comment: NB It has nothing to do with `printf()` or [tag:semantics].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ISO C, a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) must be in a single line of code, unless there is a `\` character immediately before the end of the line, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    a = 16;
  
    printf("This is the first line\
    this is the second line\
    ");
}
```

However, this will print the following:

```
This is the first line    this is the second line
```

As you can see, the indentation is also being printed. This is not what you want.

What you can do is define several string literals next to each other, on separate lines, adding a `\n` [escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape) as necessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    a = 16;
  
    printf(
        "This is the first line\n"
        "this is the second line\n"
    );
}
```

Adjacent string literals will be automatically merged in [phase 6 of the translation process](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases#Phase_6).

This program has the desired output:

```
This is the first line
this is the second line
```

Comment: Nicely  and correctly explained.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a `\` character at the end of a C source code line to combine it with the next line:

```
    printf("This is the first line\
    this is the second line\
    ");
```

That will print:

```
This is the first line    this is the second line    ∎
```

(The `∎` marks the end of the output.)

To put actual newline characters in the string literal, the `\n` escape sequence may be used:

```
    printf("This is the first line\n\
    this is the second line\n\
    ");
```

That will print:

```
This is the first line↩
    this is the second line↩
    ∎
```

(The `∎` marks the end of the output. The `↩` marks the end of a line.)

To avoid the extra spaces at the start of the second and third lines, remove the spaces from the beginning of the continuation lines:

```
    printf("This is the first line\n\
this is the second line\n\
");
```

That will print:

```
This is the first line↩
this is the second line↩
∎
```

(The `∎` marks the end of the output. The `↩` marks the end of a line.)

It is neater to replace the use of the line continuation with string literal concatenation as follows:

```
    printf("This is the first line\n"
        "this is the second line\n");
```

That will print:

```
This is the first line↩
this is the second line↩
∎
```

(The `∎` marks the end of the output. The `↩` marks the end of a line.)